# MRUnit with Standalone Mode

Tags: hadoop, junit, mrunit

Is it possible to run MRUnit in standalone mode?  To combine the benefits of isolated mappers/reducers with a transparent and simple output check that still reads from local disk (I want to test a particular FileSYstem implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mrunit runs in standalone mode, iirc. Just make sure to set fs.default.name to 'local' in your configuration.

Comment: Does it write output files to disk ?

Comment: Yes, it writes data to whatever you set the output location to.